# How to update value of one variable all part of the code using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried to update a global variable using JavaScript after each call of a method. But its not updating. The thing I tried, declare a variable and declare a variable to initialize it by calling a method and then tried to add those. Several times, I need to do this. But its not adding. Can't I do this using JavaScript?

```
function finalResult() {

    var result = "";


    function addString(str1, str2) {
        return str1 + str2;
    }

    var filter1 = addString("a", "b");
    result += filter1;

    var filter2 = addString("c", "d");
    result += filter2;

    console.log(result);  // gives me -> empty string (ie the first time initialized value)

}
```

And my expected output is like: abcd

Comment: Have you tried adding your var result = "" outside of finalResult before calling it? If so, where do you see that the output was not what it was expected?

Comment: actually, i added console.log() to check that and getting only "".

Comment: Was it added inside of the function or outside ? Because the var "result" is declared inside the function and cannot be seen outside. If you add console.log(result) before your last "}", you should see that the result is as expected.

Comment: It works fine, your code is perfect. Try calling the function right after you defined it. Look at the fiddle in your console https://jsfiddle.net/mh9fsuk6/

Comment: Here is a good read if you want to understand why Javascript variables declaration behave that way! https://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make variable global, declare it outside function or change `var result = "";` to `result = "";`. , your code seems to work fine-https://jsfiddle.net/oevr4rwm/1/

```
function finalResult() {    
    result = "";    

    function addString(str1, str2) {
        return str1 + str2;
    }    

    var filter1 = addString("a", "b");
    result += filter1;

    var filter2 = addString("c", "d");
    result += filter2;     
}

finalResult();    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the string in `finalResult`.

```
function finalResult() {
    var result = "";

    function addString(str1, str2) {
        return str1 + str2;
    }

    var filter1 = addString("a", "b");
    result += filter1;

    var filter2 = addString("c", "d");
    result += filter2;

    console.log(result) // if you want to log "abcd" to the console when you invoke the function elsewhere in your code
    return result;      // if you want the function to return "abcd"
}
```